# Applying Fuzzy Logic to a Data.Frame in R (package: sets) *UPDATED*

Tags: r, dataframe, logic, fuzzy

I am using the sets package in R to create a fuzzy logic system to assign membership to three types of genetic data. I have successfully created the fuzzy universe, variables, rules, model, and successfully used `fuzzy_inference` and `gset_defuzzify` to assign membership to single observations. I would like to find a way to apply this process to a data frame containing 1.7k observations:

```
head(df)
  cell.line  Gene mutation Expression Copy.Number
1     SCC-4 ABCB1        0          0           1
2    CAL-27 ABCC3       -2          1           0    
3    CAL-27  ABL1       -4          0           0    
4    SCC-15   ACE        0         -1           0    
5    CAL-27  ACE2        0          1           0
6    SCC-15 ACER1        0         -1           0
```

I would like to run the following code and apply to my entire dataframe and export the result of `gset_expression` for each observation into a new column.

```
example.1 <- fuzzy_inference(model, list(mut = df$mutation, exp = df$Expression, CN = df$Copy.Number))
df$fuzzy <- gset_defuzzify(example.1, "centroid")
```

The code works if I manually enter the contents of each column, however I would like to apply this function over my entire data set (full set includes >1,000 rows).

```
example <- fuzzy_inference(model, list(mut = 0, exp = 0, CN = 1))
gset_defuzzify(example, "centroid")
>[1] 0.8392016
example.2 <- fuzzy_inference(model, list(mut = -2, exp = 1, CN = 0))
gset_defuzzify(example.2, "centroid")
>[1] 1.160809
```

I think I'll need an apply function, however I am newer to R and find myself stuck. I have tried a few iterations of the following:

```
Fuzzy <- do.call(rbind, apply(df, 1, function(x) + 
fuzzy_inference(model, 
list(mut = df$mutation, exp = df$Expression, CN = df$Copy.Number) + ))) 
Error in df$mutation : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I have also tried to use apply to no avail:

```
apply(df, 1, function(row){
    m <- row['mutation']
    e <- row['Expression']
    c <- row['Copy.Number']
    fuzzify <- fuzzy_inference(model, list(mut = m, exp = e, CN = c))
   gset_defuzzify(fuzzify, "centroid")
})

>  1   2   3   4   5   6 
>NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

apply(df, 1,                                        

     function(x) {

       example.3 <- fuzzy_inference(model, 
                    list(mut = x['mutation'], exp = x['Expression'], 
                    CN = x['Copy.Number']))

       gset_defuzzify(example.2, "centroid")

   })

>   1.160809 1.160809 1.160809 1.160809 1.160809 1.160809
```

Is this possible? Thanks for your help!

Nathan

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I found a solution, but it is not very elegant. If anyone has any ideas of how to solve the problem in a less convoluted way, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

```
df$rownm <- rownames(df)
fuzz.1 <- function(y){
    fuzzify <- fuzzy_inference(model, list(mut = df[y,'mutation'], exp = df[y,'Expression'], CN = df[y,'Copy.Number']))
   gset_defuzzify(fuzzify, "centroid")}
df$membership <- sapply(df$rownm, fuzz.1) 

head(df[1:2,])
      cell.line  Gene mutation Expression Copy.Number rownm membership
    1     SCC-4 ABCB1        0          0           1     1          0.8392016
    2    CAL-27 ABCC3       -2          1           0     2          1.160809
```

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? What did you get as a result?

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer - I think I'll need an apply function, however I am newer to R and find myself stuck. I have tried a few iterations of the following: [`code'](> Fuzzy <- do.call(rbind, apply(df, 1, function(x)
+   fuzzy_inference(model, list(mut = x$mutation, exp = x$Expression, CN = x$Copy.Number)
+ )))
Error in x$mutation : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors)

Comment: Can you please update this in your post? Thanks.

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer Will do. Thanks!

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer I updated with some more information and another failed attempt. I appreciate your help so far.